# jQuery: Cannot upload file via input click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

An area of my page allows users to drag and drop files and have it upload (for debugging, I am having it console.log the filename. I am trying to also add the ability to click on the div to bring up the file dialog window so they can upload a file through there. For some reason, this does not work. Am I using `event.datatransfer.files` incorrectly?

[Here is my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xnztbt84/) code.

The important bits are:

```
dropArea.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
function handleClick(event) {
    $("#FileUpload").trigger('click');
    console.log(event.dataTransfer.files[0]['name']);
}
```

Comment: Why would the click eventObject on the div have files?

Comment: I am not sure. With drag and drop, I would have to use `processFiles(event.dataTransfer.files);` for files to upload. I am trying to do the same for files from the file dialog

Comment: Right, but in this case the div has nothing to do with selecting files, that's done with the fileInput. You would need to use the fileInput's change event to know when a file has been selected.

Comment: Ah I see. So how would i upload the files that the user selects through the dialog

Comment: Also, why the down votes? I asked a question to the best of my limited ability and provided an example.

Comment: *"You would need to use the fileInput's change event to know when a file has been selected."* You would also need to use the fileInput to get the selected files.

Comment: I added `$("#FileUpload").on('change',function(){alert(this.files[0].name);});` to my code and it seems it is being called twice even when I click once.

Comment: If you click the dragbox again does it then happen 3 times?

Comment: you can't open a file dialog from JS, the user needs to click it. you can use a <label> to extend the clickzone, and you can use a clear input in front of something else that looks nicer.

Comment: @dandavis i mean... his jsfiddle seems to do it just fine, at least in my browser. pretty sure it doesn't work everywhere though.

Comment: @KevinB: It happens 4 times

Comment: @dandavis: I have the file input in the div but I have it hidden. When a user clicks the div, the file dialog box appears.

Comment: @Bijan Then the problem lies with where you are binding the change event. don't bind events inside of events that may happen more than once.

Comment: You are correct. That solves my (sub)problem. Now I still need to be able to upload the users file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Per the comments, I had to bind on the change event. The following solved my issue:

```
$("#FileUpload").on('change',function(){
    //console.log(this.files);
    processFiles(this.files);
});
```

`this.files` contains a FileList of all the files